# Why multiple identical cells EMF is equal to only one cells EMF in parallel combination? What happens inside the circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, batteries

Cells emf is identical. Suppose three cell connected via parallel combination with a single resistance. Why the emf is equal to only one cells emf?

Comment: What do you know in general about components wired in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Because three cells in *parallel* behave just as if they were one big cell, with *three times the surface area* inside them for the electrochemical reactions to occur upon. This means that this one bigger cell can dump current at *three times* the rate of a single smaller cell, while operating at exactly the same *voltage*- because the electrochemistry that determines the voltage inside the bigger cell is exactly the same as that inside the smaller cell(s).